# Pygame MemoryError

Tags: python, memory, audio, pygame

HI i wrote a simple block collecting program that was working just fine and dandy until i added sound. Then all the sudden i get a MemoryError which is something ive never seen before.

my code is attached along with the sound(wav) file that seem to be the problem. Any help would be great, and yes the code and the sound are in the same folder along with tons of other programs and pictures and stuff.

```
import pygame
import random
import pygame.mixer

winsound=pygame.mixer.Sound('winning.wav')
collectsound=pygame.mixer.Sound('blip.wav')
#Define colors

black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

#Class represents ball, derives from Sprite class in pygame

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Constructor. Pass in the color of the block and its x and y pos.
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
            # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

            # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
            # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
            self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
            self.image.fill(color)

            # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
            # image.
            # Update the position of this object by setting the values 
            # of rect.x and rect.y
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

winsound=pygame.mixer.Sound('winning.wav')
collectsound=pygame.mixer.Sound('blip.wav')

#Set width and height of screen

screen_width=700
screen_height=400
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Attack!')

#List of sprites. Each block is added to this list. List is managed by RenderPlain()

block_list=pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()

#List of every sprite

all_sprites_list=pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()

for i in range(50):
    #create instance of block
    block=Block(black,20,14)

    #set random location for the block
    block.rect.x=random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y=random.randrange(screen_height)

    #Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)


#Create red player block
player=Block(red,20,15)
all_sprites_list.add(player)

done=False

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

score=0

#-------Main Program Loop-------

while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #User did something
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: #If user clicked close
            done=True #Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    #Clear screen
    screen.fill(white)

    #Get current mouse position. This returns the position as a list of two numbers
    pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #Fetch x and y out of list, like letters out of strung, set player object
    #to location of the mouse

    player.rect.x=pos[0]
    player.rect.y=pos[1]


    #Check if player block has collidied with anything...were still in a loop
    block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    #Check list of collisions.
    if len(block_hit_list) >0:
        score +=len(block_hit_list)
        print( score )
        collectsound.play()
    elif score==50:
        print('YOU WIN!!\n')
        done=True
        winsound.play()



    #Draw all the sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    #Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    #Update screen
    pygame.display.flip()



pygame.quit()
```

So when i run the code i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zackbaker/Desktop/PythonFolder/BlockCollecter.py", line 4, in <module>
    sound=pygame.mixer.Sound('winning.wav')
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have to initialize the mixer first, before using sounds.

```
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
# Read the docs to know what these numbers are
```