# Collision detection issue (pygame), "collision detected" isn't printed once 2 surfaces hover over each other

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, sprite, platform

[MEMORY ISSUE PROBLEM DELETED FROM POST]

Hey guys I'm new to pygame and I have a few small issues. Python shell wont print collission detected once the jetfighter rect collides with that of the tarantula before the mouse button's clicked but instead the surfaces hover past each other, no error given. The if statement on line 54 works as intended so I'm a little bit stumped as to why the statement on line 61 doesn't work as I expect it to. If anyone can shed some light onto my problem, I will greatly appreciate it.

Code:

```
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer 
from pygame.locals import *
import random 
pygame.init()

bif="space.jpg"
jf="spacefightersprite.png"
enemy="TarantulaSpaceFighter.png"

laser=pygame.mixer.Sound("LaserBlast.wav")
explosionsound=pygame.mixer.Sound("Explosion.wav") 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800),0,32)
caption=pygame.display.set_caption("Jet Fighter X") 
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
jetfighterx=pygame.image.load(jf)
jetfighterx=pygame.transform.scale(jetfighterx, (400,400)) 
tarantula=pygame.image.load(enemy)
tarantula=pygame.transform.scale(tarantula, (100,100))
laserblast=pygame.image.load("C:\Python27\laser.png")
explosion=pygame.image.load("C:\Python27\explosion.png")
explosion=pygame.transform.scale(explosion, (150,150)) 

ex,ey=450,0
movex,movey=0,0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=300
shoot_y=0
collision=False 
loop=True 

while True:
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) 
    mx,my=pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE or event.key==K_q:
                sys.exit() 
        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            laserblast=pygame.image.load("C:\Python27\laser.png")
            laser.play()
            shoot_y=my-200
            shoot_x=mx-16
    if loop==True:
        if shoot_y>0:
            screen.blit(laserblast, (shoot_x, shoot_y))       
            shoot_y-=10
            laserblast_rect=laserblast.get_rect(center=(shoot_x, shoot_y))
            tarantula_rect=tarantula.get_rect(center=(ex, ey))
            jetfighterx_rect=jetfighterx.get_rect(center=(mx, my)) 
            if laserblast_rect.colliderect(tarantula_rect):
                laserblast=pygame.transform.scale(laserblast,(0,0)) 
                screen.blit(explosion, (ex, ey-50))
                explosionsound.play()
                collision=True
            elif jetfighterx_rect.colliderect(tarantula_rect):
                print "Collision detected"
            pygame.display.update()


    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(jetfighterx,(mx-200,my-200))
    if collision==False:
        screen.blit(tarantula, (ex, ey))

    milli=clock.tick()
    seconds=milli/1000. 
    dmy=seconds*speed
    ey+=dmy

    if ey>800:
        collision=False
        ey=0
        ex=random.randint(50,800)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions here, at least.  On StackOverflow, you'll want to limit your posts to a single question.

The second question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690301/pygame-memoryerror).

Comment: okay understood, do you at least have an idea of how I should deal with my first issue? I haven't come across any questions on here that are similar to that...btw I've edited my original post.

Comment: You might get better visibility asking the question again with the correct title.